# If there exists a bounded operator $T:X \to Y$ with $T^{-1}$ bounded then X is Banach iff Y is Banach

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

I have been asked to show that if there exists a bounded operator $T:X \to Y$  with $T^{-1}$ bounded then X is Banach iff Y is Banach.

I have shown it for $T$ a **linear** operator.  But I can't use the same trick for a bounded operator which is not linear.

The trick is to use the fact that $||T^{-1}(y_n - y_m)||=||T^{-1}(y_n)-T^{-1}(y_m)||$ to show that $(T^{-1}(y_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence. And the same for $(T(y_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: How do you define non linenar bounded operator?

Comment: We have worked with linear continuous (bounded) operators, that's why I think it might be a mistake in the exercise, but I decided to ask it here in order to confirm it.

Comment: In that case you would try using $f:X\to Y$ with $f$ and $f^{-1}$ uniformly continuous. i,e, $X$ and $Y$ uniformly homeomorfhic. Then, $X$ is complete iff $Y$ is complete.

Comment: The "linear" is probably implicit. Bounded nonlinear operators need not be continuous (bounded linear operators need not be continuous in all situations too, but for linear maps between normed spaces, being bounded is equivalent to being continuous), and I am sceptical about the assertion if the linearity of $T$ is not assumed.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer♦ Yes, that is why I asked, because I wanted to make sure linar was implicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that the definition of a bounded operator is

> An operator $A \colon X \to Y$ is *bounded* if for every bounded $S\subset X$ the image $A(S)$ is a bounded subset of $Y$,

the linearity of $T$ *must* be implicitly assumed in that exercise, since we can give counterexamples with nonlinear bounded operators.

Let $1 \leqslant p < q \leqslant +\infty$, and consider $X = \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ endowed with the $\ell^p$-norm, and $Y$ the same space endowed with the $\ell^q$-norm. Presumably it is known that then $X$ is a Banach space, and $Y$ an incomplete normed space.

However, for every $\rho > 0$, the cardinality of the spheres $S_{\rho}^r = \{ x : \lVert x\rVert_r = \rho\}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$ for either $r\in \{p,q\}$, so there a bijection $t \colon S_1^p \to S_1^q$. Defining $T\colon X \to Y$ by $T(x) = \lVert x\rVert\cdot t(x/\lVert x\rVert)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $T(0) = 0$, we thus have a bounded bijection with bounded inverse.

If a different definition of a nonlinear bounded operator is used, the assertion might hold without the linearity assumption.